Should we use different structs for request and response?
I have no prior backend experience and I started working on a new project. I've checked many repositories for inspiration and what I saw was that half of them use the same struct for both request and response, and half use separate structs.
Is there a right way? In frontend we usually use different objects for request and response, but what about backend?
For example:
package domain

type SignIn struct {
        Email    string `json:"email"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
}

would be used as a request object, and
package domain

type SignInResponse struct {
        Email         string `json:"email"`
        UID           string `json:"UID"`
        AccessToken   string `json:"access_token"`
        RefreshToken  string `json:"refresh_token"`
}

would be used as a response object.
It kinda make sense to have 2 separate structs for request and response since they have different fields. Or should we use only one and populate just the fields we need?
What about if they have same fields?

Why would you use the same struct if request and response contain different data?

@mkrieger1 Yes, it doesn't make any sense, even using composition as NotX mentioned in his answer, and checking those repositories confused me a lot. Even if it does hold the same data, to me makes the logic too coupled to be worth one single model struct.

What you could use is composition:
type SignIn struct {
    Email    string `json:"email"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
}

type SignInResponse struct {
        SignIn
        AccessToken   string `json:"access_token"`
        RefreshToken  string `json:"refresh_token"`
}

Even the json tags will carry over. Of course, the name SignIn doesn't make that much sense then anymore.
I'ld go with duplicate, independend structs, though: it serves the clarity (request logic is decoupled from the response logic), and in my experience the more elaborate things become in the further development, the more composition gets in your way b/c things don't match anymore the way did in the beginning.
I think composition is mostly a good idea when 1. you want to make explicit that some structs share some logical relation, or 2. you want to make some method receivers of the inner struct available from the outer one (1. should be a precondition here).

Thanks a lot for the information. I stand by your point because I was thinking the same way. Better have a bit more code with an easy to understand logic than passing same struct in many different layers.
